# How to solve "package is in a very bad inconsistent state"

Tags: release-freya

While installing `ibus-unikey` I got this error

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
The following NEW packages will be installed: 
ibus-unikey 
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
Need to get 0 B/267 kB of archives. 
After this operation, 303 kB of additional disk space will be used. 
Selecting previously unselected package ibus-unikey. 
(Reading database ... 227994 files and directories currently installed.) 
 Preparing to unpack .../ibus-unikey_0.6.1-1build2_amd64.deb ... 
 Unpacking ibus-unikey (0.6.1-1build2) ... 
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure): 
package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should 
reinstall it before attempting configuration 
Setting up ibus-unikey (0.6.1-1build2) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
apport 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So far I have tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ibus-unikey

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ibus-unikey

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --force-depends ibus-unikey

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

But still same erors.

I am using freya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ibus-unikey.* /tmp/

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq ibus-unikey

sudo apt-get remove ibus-unikey

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now install `ibus-unikey`

```
sudo apt-get install ibus-unikey
```

---

To make general solution:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.* /tmp/

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>

sudo apt-get remove <packagename>

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

<sub>source [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=5216367#post5216367)</sub>